# WebSphere - Security role to user/group mapping

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

We are creating a JSP application as a Maven project (formerly existed but not as Maven). We've been following other working applications and we have done everything the same way. Our project structure consists of 3 modules (web, EAR and main module). We have 2 groups in our Admin console and in our web.xml as security roles, however WebSphere doesn't recognize them as mapped.

Applications -> Application Types -> Websphere enterprise applications -> [our ear name] -> Security role to user/group mapping

The groups appear there (they have the same names in the web.xml and Admin console), however nothing is mapped, and we are unable to map the groups. Literally, the arrows that allow you to select the groups are not working when clicked.

I have tried unchecking 'Minimize application files copied to the server' and also tried switching to 'Run application with resources on Server'

I have even tried creating an ibm-application-bnd.xml and putting it in every META-INF folder I could find. Any ideas would be appreciated.

web.xml sample:

```
<security-role>
    <description>Application User</description>
    <role-name>TESTUSER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

ibm-application-bnd.xml sample:

```
<security-role name="TESTUSER">
    <group name="TESTUSER" />
</security-role>
```

Comment: The binding file should be in your EAR. Is administrative security and application security enabled on your WAS profile?

Comment: Yes and yes. The bnd file was in the EAR.

Comment: We were able to map the groups via Chrome, however they become unmapped whenever we restart the server.